# Inconsistent validation alerts in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, validation

I'm having some problems getting the devise validation helpers to be the same for login and signup.

When a user fails a signs up or fills out the forgot password incorrectly form the devise error notification is shown.  Red box on top with a message and then each problem field is highlighted in red.  This is the desired outcome.

When a user incorrectly fills out the login form I'm getting a different type of validation.  Rather than highlighting the problem fields in red, I am getting a standard flash notice that is tied into the devise locales file.

```
  devise:
    failure:
      invalid: 'Invalid email or password.
```

Here is the view:

```
- provide(:title, "Login")
.devise-form-box
  %h2 Login
  = simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-vertical' }) do |f|
    = f.error_notification
    = f.input :email, :autofocus => true, :placeholder => "Email Address"
    = f.input :password, :placeholder => "Password"
    = f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable?
    .clearfix
    = f.button :submit, "Login", :class => 'btn-primary btn-medium'
  = render "devise/shared/links"
```

Any ideas on why the login form isn't using the same validation method as sign up or forgot password?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have such html elements to show errors, how can you expect to see them?

Simple solution is to add the error part under the `form_for`.

```
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
```

See devise default template for reference.

If you want to further customize the error messages, it's easy as well, you can see `devise_error_message!` is simply a manipulation of error message: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb. So you can check the error views in the normal scaffold template for reference to improve it if needed.

Comment: The HTML isn't explicitly in the other views either. I added the suggestion you made but it still is not working.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong.  The login form isn't supposed to highlight incorrect fields like the signup form.

Comment: I think you are right. It's better to display vague message on login.

Comment: No, just not built into devise.